# Как имитировать ввод текста в input password

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт на angular, сайт не мой. Хочу немного оптимизировать работу с ним для себя.
Нужно в поле **input type="password"** или **#password** вставить свой пароль.

Просто вставить свой пароль в это поле не проблема:

```
$("input[name='password']").val('test');
```

Пароль вставляется, но при нажатии на кнопку отправки формы - сайт отвечает что пароль я не ввел. И так он отвечает до тех пор покуда реально не введешь текст клавиатурой.

Вот их input:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" class="rginput ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched error" ng-class="{'error': field$invalid('password')}" ng-model="password" ng-keyup="onPasswordKeyUp()" required="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
```

Я подозреваю что это из-за **ng-keyup="onPasswordKeyUp()"**

Как заставить думать сайт что текст введен с клавиатуры?

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Так работает `$("input[name='password']").val('test').keyup();`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет, говорит что пароль не введен

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, в точности такой же код как вы предоставили выполнял. отвечает что пароль не введен, хоть видно что в поле появились символы

Comment: Покажите еще код `onPasswordKeyUp()`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov дело в том что у меня нет этого кода. сайт не мой. вот этот сайт https://www.betstarsnj.com/ , а вот сюда пароль вводить нужно: http://prntscr.com/o5ulsh

Comment: Я понимаю, что сайт не ваш. Но не вижу проблем найти в исходниках сайта эту функцию

Comment: Если вы хотите залогинится, вам не надо имитировать нажатие клавиш. Достаточно послать правильный GET/POST запрос на авторизацию из консоли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведенный вами сайт использует `AngularJs 1.6`.

Данный способ будет работать только для данного сайта и только для `AngularJs`.

Необходимо написать следующий код в консоли:

```
var rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app="ram"]')).injector().get('$rootScope'); 
rootScope.$$childHead.password = rootScope.$$childHead.username ='123'; 
rootScope.$apply();
```

После этого  логин и пароль в форме примут значение `'123'`.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить Ваше решение? Как написать аналогичное без AngularJs?

Comment: И почему в случае автора не работает?

Comment: @Влад Объяснять долго и точно в комментарии не поместится :) В двух словах если - angular хранит значение инпутов на форме во внутреннем состоянии и при каждом чихе перезаписывает значения в инпутах. Выход - менять внутреннее состояние, что мой код и делает.