# Как попадают значения в $scope.$$childHead.input в angular 1?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

Необходимо взять значение из `angular.copy($scope.$$childHead.input, ....).`
В аналогичном коде значения приходят. У меня не приходят и пишет `undefined`.
Как они туда попадают с формы?

---

> **upd2**

На форме присутствуют input-поля

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
       <div ng-model="input" fb-form="{{id}}"></div>
</form>
//рядом кнопка для save c on-click=onSaveClick()
```

> **1) file2.js**

Потом срабатывает controller, который чекает id и выстраивает input массив:

```
.controller('fbFormController', [
        '$scope', '$injector', function ($scope, $injector)
        {
            //здесь инициализация input
        }
```

> **2) file3.js**

Здесь лежит $on для save:

```
$scope.onSaveClick = function ()
{
    ...
    $scope.$root.$broadcast($scope.broadcastChannel.save);
};
```

> **3) file4.js**

И здесь уже срабатывает save:

```
$scope.$on($scope.broadcastChannel.save, function (event)
{
...
$validator.validate($scope).success(function()
 {
   save();
 }
}

function save()
{
  ...
  var inputCopy = formService.transformInputValues(angular.copy($scope.$$childHead.input), $scope.model.linkEditor.selectedForm.layout);
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Для каждого приложения будет свой путь для получения значений. Этот путь зависит от многих факторов.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko пример можете привести, простой, как туда могут попасть данные?

Comment: Это я должен попросить был у вас пример сайта)

Comment: Вот здесь похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995873/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-input-password/996219#996219

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не могу пример, это на проекте встретилось. Мне бы просто принцип, как оно само подсасывает значения с формы.  ТСтрока о которой говорю встречается один раз, добавил выше.

Comment: Свойство $$childHead` не документировано, и, соответственно, без крайней нужды лучше его не использовать. Оно указывает на первый дочерний scope. А значения туда попадают так же, как и в любой другой scope, обычно через ng-model.

Comment: @Yaant ng-model="input" у меня на форме стоит, значит $scope.input отправляет в $$childhead.input?

Comment: Если `input` находится в первом дочернем scope по отношению к `$scope`, то да, `$scope.$$childHead.input` будет соответствовать ему. Если нет, то нет.

Comment: @Yaant а какой в этой директиве практический смысл? Зачем она может применяться?

Comment: Это свойство используется самим ангуляром для внутренних нужд, например для броадкаста событий. Если возникло желание или, того хуже, необходимость использовать его в своем коде, значит Вы делаете что-то не так. :)

Comment: @Yaant я angular 1 не люблю, но на проекте используется и пришла задача, и там уже всунут childHead( . Оформите может все ваши комментарии одним ответом, выберу как правильный ответ.

Comment: Если бы вы привели пример, как и где используется `$$childHead`, тогда возможно можно было бы дать ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko посмотрите, добавил чуть больше кода

Comment: Как видно из вашего кода, событие `broadcastChannel.save` вызывается по цепочки вниз из `$root`. Соответсвенно `$scope.$on` может быть в любом месте и **не обязательно** `$scope.$$childHead` будет указывать на $scope от `fbFormController`. Выходи - переписать весь этот ужасный код. Ну или передавать в событии `$scope`, у которого надо взять `input`. За последствие второго варианта я не отвечаю :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko код ужасный, Вы правы. А можете объяснить, как можно в $$childHead input всандалить, чтобы много переписывать не пришлось?

Comment: Не надо ничего всандаливать. Надо при передаче событии `broadcastChannel.save` передавать либо `$scope` либо объект с даныыми, которые нужны `$scope.$on`.

Answer (score 1):

При вызове события `broadcastChannel.save` можно передавать любые данные. В данном случае можно передать значение `input`.

```
$scope.onSaveLinkEditorClick = function ()
{
    ...
    $scope.$root.$broadcast($scope.broadcastChannel.save,{input:$scope.input});
};
```

При получении события `broadcastChannel.save` переданные данные можно получить.

```
$scope.$on($scope.broadcastChannel.save, function (event, data)
{
...
$validator.validate($scope).success(function()
 {
   save();
 }
}

function save()
{
  ...
  // если data есть, то берем его, если нету, то пытаемся найти через $scope.$$childHead
  var inputCopy = formService.transformInputValues(angular.copy(data? data.input: $scope.$$childHead.input), $scope.model.linkEditor.selectedForm.layout);
  ...
 }
```

Comment: broadcastChannel.save находится в другом месте, где у $scope нет input

Comment: @Lancelot Это надо отразить в вопросе. Каким образом и где вызывается `onSaveLinkEditorClick`?

Comment: Я пометил выше, в какой последовательности файлы вызываются. 1 - форма, где кнопка, 2 - файл, где инпут, в 3ем лежит фунция для клика (инициализится броадкаст), 4 - броадкаст

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Наверное, воспроизводимый пример был бы лучше. Хотя, $scope в *file3.js* не тот же самый, что и в файле *file2.js*?

Comment: Извиняюсь, там file3.js два раза был) Да, в file2.js строится input, file3.js посредник, и каким-то непонятным мне образом в file4.js оказывается input. Дополнительно через параметры при клике ничего не передаётся (в аналогичном рабочем примере)

Comment: Извините, но вы не ответила на мой вопрос. `$scope` в **file3.js** тот же самый, что и в файле **file2.js**?

Comment: $scope отличаются, да, разные

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95663/discussion-between-stepan-kasyanenko-and-lancelot).